# How to plot a regression line on a timeseries line plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scikit-learn, time-series

I have a question about the value of the slope in degrees which I have calculated below:

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np

df = yf.download('aapl', '2015-01-01', '2021-01-01')
df.rename(columns = {'Adj Close' : 'Adj_close'}, inplace= True)

x1 = pd.Timestamp('2019-01-02')
x2 = df.index[-1]
y1 = df[df.index == x1].Adj_close[0]
y2 = df[df.index == x2].Adj_close[0]

slope = (y2 - y1)/ (x2 - x1).days
angle = round(np.rad2deg(np.arctan2(y2 - y1, (x2 - x1).days)), 1)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize= (15, 6))
ax1.grid(True, linestyle= ':')
ax1.set_zorder(1)
ax1.set_frame_on(False)
ax1.plot(df.index, df.Adj_close, c= 'k', lw= 0.8)
ax1.plot([x1, x2], [y1, y2], c= 'k')


ax1.set_xlim(df.index[0], df.index[-1])
plt.show()
```

It returns the value of the angle of the slope as 7.3 degrees. Which doesnt look true looking at the chart:
[image]

It looks close to 45 degrees. What is wrong here?

Here is the line for which I need to calculate the angle:
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- The implementation in the OP is not the correct way to determine, or plot a linear model. As such, the question about determining the angle to plot the line is bypassed, and a more rigorous approach to plotting the regression line is shown.
- **A regression line can be added by converting the datetime dates to ordinal.** The model can be calculated with `sklearn`, or added to the plot with `seaborn.regplot`, as show below.
- Plot the full data with [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)
- **Tested in `python 3.8.11`, `pandas 1.3.2`, `matplotlib 3.4.3`, `seaborn 0.11.2`, `sklearn 0.24.2`**

### Imports and Data

```py
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

# download the data
df = yf.download('aapl', '2015-01-01', '2021-01-01')

# convert the datetime index to ordinal values, which can be used to plot a regression line
df.index = df.index.map(pd.Timestamp.toordinal)

# display(df.iloc[:5, [4]])
        Adj Close
Date             
735600  24.782110
735603  24.083958
735604  24.086227
735605  24.423975
735606  25.362394

# convert the regression line start date to ordinal
x1 = pd.to_datetime('2019-01-02').toordinal()

# data slice for the regression line
data=df.loc[x1:].reset_index()
```

### Plot a Regression Line with seaborn

- Using [`seaborn.regplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.regplot.html) no calculations are required to add the regression line to the line plot of the data.
- Convert the x-axis labels to datetime format
- Play around with the xticks and labels if you need the endpoints adjusted.

```
# plot the Adj Close data
ax1 = df.plot(y='Adj Close', c='k', figsize=(15, 6), grid=True, legend=False,
              title='Adjusted Close with Regression Line from 2019-01-02')

# add a regression line
sns.regplot(data=data, x='Date', y='Adj Close', ax=ax1, color='magenta', scatter_kws={'s': 7}, label='Linear Model', scatter=False)

ax1.set_xlim(df.index[0], df.index[-1])

# convert the axis back to datetime
xticks = ax1.get_xticks()
labels = [pd.Timestamp.fromordinal(int(label)).date() for label in xticks]
ax1.set_xticks(xticks)
ax1.set_xticklabels(labels)

ax1.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image]

### Calculate the Linear Model

- Use [`sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) to calculate any desired points from the linear model, and then plot the corresponding line with [`matplotlib.pyplot.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html)
- In regards to your other question, [Extending the trendline of a stock chart to the right](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68919476/7758804), you would calculate the model over a specified range, and then extend the line by predicting `y1` and `y2`, given `x1` and `x2`.
- This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69693872/7758804) shows how to convert the ordinal axis values back to a date format.

```py
# create the model
model = LinearRegression()

# extract x and y from dataframe data
x = data[['Date']]
y = data[['Adj Close']]

# fit the mode
model.fit(x, y)

# print the slope and intercept if desired
print('intercept:', model.intercept_)
print('slope:', model.coef_)

intercept: [-90078.45713565]
slope: [[0.1222514]]

# calculate y1, given x1
y1 = model.predict(np.array([[x1]]))

print(y1)
array([[28.27904095]])

# calculate y2, given the last date in data
x2 = data.Date.iloc[-1]
y2 = model.predict(np.array([[x2]]))

print(y2)
array([[117.40030862]])

# this can be added to `ax1` with
ax1 = df.plot(y='Adj Close', c='k', figsize=(15, 6), grid=True, legend=False,
              title='Adjusted Close with Regression Line from 2019-01-02')
ax1.plot([x1, x2], [y1[0][0], y2[0][0]], label='Linear Model', c='magenta')
ax1.legend()
```

[image]

### Angle of the Slope

- This is an artifact of the aspect of the `axes`, which is not equal for `x` and `y`. When the aspect is equal, see that the slope is 7.0 deg.

```py
x = x2 - x1
y = y2[0][0] - y1[0][0]
slope = y / x

print(round(slope, 7) == round(model.coef_[0][0], 7))
[out]:
True

angle = round(np.rad2deg(np.arctan2(y, x)), 1)
print(angle)
[out]:
7.0

# given the existing plot
ax1 = df.plot(y='Adj Close', c='k', figsize=(15, 6), grid=True, legend=False,
              title='Adjusted Close with Regression Line from 2019-01-02')
ax1.plot([x1, x2], [y1[0][0], y2[0][0]], label='Linear Model', c='magenta')

# make the aspect equal
ax1.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, got it. Its because of the figure size aspect ratio that it feels like it should have a larger angle.