# How to apply gradient fill with datetime on x-axis using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

I am trying to use the gradient fill under curves in matplotlib with `datetime` values on x-axis using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29347731/4576447). I tried converting the datetime values to `float` to fix this, but that was not helpful.

The MWE and the error is given below. How to apply gradient fill under curves with datetime values on x-axis in matplotlib?

**MWE**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
from PIL import ImageFilter
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

np.random.seed(1977)
def demo_blur_underside():
    for _ in range(5):
        # gradient_fill(*generate_data(100), zfunc=None) # original
        gradient_fill(*generate_data(100), zfunc=zfunc)
    plt.show()

def generate_data(num):
    x = np.linspace(0, 100, num)
    y = np.random.normal(0, 1, num).cumsum()
    return x, y

def zfunc(x, y, fill_color='k', alpha=1.0):
    scale = 10
    x = (x*scale).astype(int)
    y = (y*scale).astype(int)
    xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()

    w, h = xmax-xmin, ymax-ymin
    z = np.empty((h, w, 4), dtype=float)
    rgb = mcolors.colorConverter.to_rgb(fill_color)
    z[:,:,:3] = rgb

    # Build a z-alpha array which is 1 near the line and 0 at the bottom.
    img = Image.new('L', (w, h), 0)  
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    xy = (np.column_stack([x, y]))
    xy -= xmin, ymin
    # Draw a blurred line using PIL
    draw.line(map(tuple, xy.tolist()), fill=255, width=15)
    img = img.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(radius=100))
    # Convert the PIL image to an array
    zalpha = np.asarray(img).astype(float) 
    zalpha *= alpha/zalpha.max()
    # make the alphas melt to zero at the bottom
    n = zalpha.shape[0] // 4
    zalpha[:n] *= np.linspace(0, 1, n)[:, None]
    z[:,:,-1] = zalpha
    return z

def gradient_fill(x, y, fill_color=None, ax=None, zfunc=None, **kwargs):
    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()

    line, = ax.plot(x, y, **kwargs)
    if fill_color is None:
        fill_color = line.get_color()

    zorder = line.get_zorder()
    alpha = line.get_alpha()
    alpha = 1.0 if alpha is None else alpha

    if zfunc is None:
        h, w = 100, 1
        z = np.empty((h, w, 4), dtype=float)
        rgb = mcolors.colorConverter.to_rgb(fill_color)
        z[:,:,:3] = rgb
        z[:,:,-1] = np.linspace(0, alpha, h)[:,None]
    else:
        z = zfunc(x, y, fill_color=fill_color, alpha=alpha)
    xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()
    im = ax.imshow(z, aspect='auto', extent=[xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax],
                   origin='lower', zorder=zorder)

    xy = np.column_stack([x, y])
    xy = np.vstack([[xmin, ymin], xy, [xmax, ymin], [xmin, ymin]])
    clip_path = patches.Polygon(xy, facecolor='none', edgecolor='none', closed=True)
    ax.add_patch(clip_path)
    im.set_clip_path(clip_path)
    ax.autoscale(True)
    return line, im

# x = np.linspace(0, 100, 100)
# y = np.sin(x) + x

x = np.arange(datetime(2010,7,1), datetime(2015,7,1), timedelta(hours=12)).astype(datetime)
y = np.linspace(0, 100, len(x))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
gradient_fill(x, y, ax=ax, zfunc=zfunc)
ax.grid()
fig.savefig("test.pdf")
plt.show()
```

**Error**

```
  File "./gradient_fill_test.py", line 95, in <module>
    gradient_fill(x, y, ax=ax, zfunc=zfunc)

  File "./radient_fill_test.py", line 69, in gradient_fill
    z = zfunc(x, y, fill_color=fill_color, alpha=alpha)

  File "./gradient_fill_test.py", line 24, in zfunc
    x = (x*scale).astype(int)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'datetime.datetime' and 'int'
```

Comment: try converting the datetime values to ordinal, there are SO answer showing how to do that

Comment: I am able to convert and plot them, but the x-axis is now in the ordinal format.

Comment: Now you have to get_xticks convert them to datetime, and set_xticks, and set_xticklabels. Similar to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69171277/7758804. If this has been helpful, feel free to upvote that answer.

Comment: Your answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/69171277/7758804 works perfectly with dates; i.e., now I am able to convert dates to ordinal and vice-versa. But time values get clipped, any recommendation on converting datetime to ordinal and vice-versa?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```py
x = np.arange(datetime(2010,7,1), datetime(2015,7,1), timedelta(hours=12)).astype(datetime)
y = np.linspace(0, 100, len(x))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
gradient_fill(mdates.date2num(x), y, ax=ax, zfunc=zfunc)
```

I couldn't actually get that to work because your `zfunc` seems to have a bug in it, but if you fix that it will get you properly labeled date ticks.

Comment: This puts the x-axis in number format. I need the x-axis to be in datetime format.

Comment: Plot(x,y) should put it in date format and then the datetime converter should accept the ordinal as well.

Comment: I agree, zfunc seems to have a bug. For some reason, I have to convert the numerical values to dates with `mdates.num2date`.