# Time series linear regression model results do not match linear regression from excel

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy, seaborn, linear-regression

I used both seaborn and sklearn to create a linear regression model for a time series data set. Both models (seaborn and sklearn) output the same slope and intercept for a simple linear model `y = mx + b`. The slope matches the excel results. However, the intercept is very different `-35874.5873` using either methods in python compared to `-1404.3` in excel.

Do I have a setting in my python code incorrect? Are the models calculated differently?

Here is data from excel.

```
Date Column: 
1/1/2002
4/1/2002
7/1/2002
10/1/2002
1/1/2003
4/1/2003
7/1/2003
10/1/2003
1/1/2004

Bicarbonate Column:
446
450
454
483
457
465
465
474
495
```

And the python script is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import scipy
from sklearn import linear_model

df = pd.read_excel(r'TestData.xls')
print(df)

Bicarbonate = df['Bicarbonate']
Date = df['Date']
DateO = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.toordinal())
df['DateO'] = DateO
print(DateO)

# Plotting the regression model with seaborn
ax1 = sns.regplot(x = 'DateO', y = 'Bicarbonate', data=df, color='magenta', label='Linear Model', ci =None, scatter=True)


# calculate slope and intercept of regression equation.
slope, intercept, r, p, se = scipy.stats.linregress(x=ax1.get_lines()[0].get_xdata(),
                                                       y=ax1.get_lines()[0].get_ydata())

print(slope)
print(intercept)
print(p)

# Linear Regression with sklearn.
x = df['DateO'].values.reshape(-1, 1)
y = df['Bicarbonate'].values.reshape(-1,1)
model = linear_model.LinearRegression().fit(x,y)
print('intercept:', model.intercept_)
print('slope:', model.coef_)
```

Answer (score 0):

- As demonstrated in [How to plot a regression line on a timeseries line plot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69170874/7758804)

  - Use `x_test = np.arange(0, ax1.get_xlim()[1]).reshape(-1, 1)` to predict with `model.predict(x_test)` and plot the data to see it crosses in the calculated point.
- The `'Date'` data has been converted to ordinal, and an ordinal date of `1` corresponds to `'0001-01-01 00:00:00'`. Considering that's `≈1971` years before the earliest date in the data, the intercept makes sense, especially given a gentle slope of `0.00243`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import scipy
from sklearn import linear_model
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
import yfinance as yf  # for sample data; conda install -c conda-forge yfinance

# download sample data
df = pd.concat((yf.download(ticker, start='1970-02-01', end='2023-09-06').assign(tkr=ticker) for ticker in ['pfe']), ignore_index=False).reset_index()

Bicarbonate = df['Open']
Date = df['Date']
df['DateO'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.toordinal())

# Plotting the regression model with seaborn
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8))
sns.regplot(x = 'DateO', y = 'Open', data=df, color='magenta', label='Linear Model', ci =None, scatter=True, ax=ax1)

# calculate slope and intercept of regression equation.
slope, intercept, r, p, se = scipy.stats.linregress(x=ax1.get_lines()[0].get_xdata(), y=ax1.get_lines()[0].get_ydata())

print('scipy intercept:', intercept)
print('scipy slope:', slope)

# Linear Regression with sklearn.
x = df['DateO'].values.reshape(-1, 1)
y = df['Open'].values.reshape(-1,1)
model = linear_model.LinearRegression().fit(x,y)
print('sklearn intercept:', model.intercept_)
print('sklearn slope:', model.coef_)

# test data with x to 0
x_test = np.arange(0, ax1.get_xlim()[1]).reshape(-1, 1)

# predicted y values
y_pred = model.predict(x_test)

# plot
ax1.plot(x_test, y_pred)

fig.suptitle(f'At x=0 the Linear Model cross y at {round(intercept)}')

ax1.margins(0)
```

```
scipy intercept: -1757.1923682739996
scipy slope: 0.002432274440853285
sklearn intercept: [-1757.19236827]
sklearn slope: [[0.00243227]]
```

[image]

[image]

---

- In order to match Excel, cast the date to `.total_seconds` from `1970`

```py
# download sample data
df = pd.concat((yf.download(ticker, start='1970-02-01', end='2023-09-06').assign(tkr=ticker) for ticker in ['pfe']), ignore_index=False).reset_index()

Bicarbonate = df['Open']
Date = df['Date']

# total seconds from 1970
df['DateO'] = (df['Date'] - datetime.fromisoformat('1970-01-01')).dt.total_seconds()

# Plotting the regression model with seaborn
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8))
sns.regplot(x = 'DateO', y = 'Open', data=df, color='magenta', label='Linear Model', ci =None, scatter=True, ax=ax1)

# calculate slope and intercept of regression equation.
slope, intercept, r, p, se = scipy.stats.linregress(x=ax1.get_lines()[0].get_xdata(), y=ax1.get_lines()[0].get_ydata())

print('scipy intercept:', intercept)
print('scipy slope:', slope)

# Linear Regression with sklearn.
x = df['DateO'].values.reshape(-1, 1)
y = df['Open'].values.reshape(-1, 1)
model = linear_model.LinearRegression().fit(x,y)
print('sklearn intercept:', model.intercept_)
print('sklearn slope:', model.coef_)

# test data with x to 0
x_test = np.arange(0, df['DateO'].max(), 10000).reshape(-1, 1)

# predicted y values
y_pred = model.predict(x_test)

# plot
ax1.plot(x_test, y_pred)

fig.suptitle(f'At x=0 the Linear Model cross y at {round(intercept)}')

ax1.margins(0)

plt.show()
```

```
scipy intercept: -7.990584566627653
scipy slope: 2.815132454691304e-08
sklearn intercept: [-7.99058457]
sklearn slope: [[2.81513245e-08]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reason why excel and python give you different intercepts is based on how datetime is treated in both softwares.

Intercept for regression on datetime series will not have any intrinsic meaning but will depend on what `0` is defined as.

#### In excel:

DateTime starts from `1970/01/01`, so if you convert any date to number 1970/01/01 will be 1 and every date will be assigned a number based on that.

#### In python:

The `datetime` package which you are using to convert by `toordinal()`, treats 0000/01/01 as the start.

If you really want to align these two (not sure why you would want to) you'll have to subtract your ordinal dates by 719163 (the ordinal number for '1970/01/01').